# Redirect Eclipse's console / ouput to a text file

Tags: java, eclipse, console, stdout

I'm doing a Java project using Eclipse. Currently by default, it shows the output in the Console. Is there any way to redirect it into a text file?

At least in python, I used to do

```
python somefile.py >  output.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open *Run Configurations* window and add a new run configuration or edit an existing one. At the configuration tabs, go to *Common* tab. There you can specify a file to direct the output.

[image]

Comment: Only works when you run a java application. And actually have a run configuration. What if you need the console output from the build itself.